# python urlib3 or request authentication with app id and app token

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I have to use either `requests` or `urllib3` with app ID and app token in python, in `curl` I am using like below and it is work

```
 curl -X POST "https://someurl/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "App-ID: app-id-xxxx" -H "Auth-Token: app-token-secret" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "body"
```

In python it is suggested `urllib3` or `requests`, but i am not sure how i need to authenitcate, I have found out couple of links but is for basic authentication

Basic authentication:

[authentication with urllib3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335825/authentication-with-urllib3)

Below link has only token secret and no token id

[python request with authentication (access_token)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825278/python-request-with-authentication-access-token)

Can anyone help me to pass/authenticate with app id and app token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add them to the `headers` dictionary:

```
response = requests.post('https://someurl', data,
    headers={'accept': 'application/json',
             'App-ID': 'app-id-xxxx', 
             'Auth-Token': 'app-token-secret',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
```